# Dash Live Stream Encoding Documentation

Tags: c++, video-streaming, live-streaming, mpeg-dash

Are there any examples or documentation of using `libdash` for live encoding and streaming? For example using a webcam as source to provide a stream with adaptive bitrate?

I've been trying to dissect the test [libdash_networkpart_test](https://github.com/bitmovin/libdash/tree/649f3400576ebe343ea3888e42bb0ae6e6cda930/libdash/libdash_networkpart_test) on the [github repo](https://github.com/bitmovin/libdash/) but I think it's mostly for vod streaming, not live.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

libdash is an open-source library that provides a C++ interface to the MPEG-DASH standard. Basically this involves parsing the MPD (Media Presentation Description) file. It does not include encoding capabilities.

If you want to use a webcam as source and provide a stream with adaptive bitrate, you first need to transform the single video stream from your webcam into an adaptive video format.

There are services available that can do that for you.

- bitmovin - the creators of the libdash library:
  https://bitmovin.com/tutorials/dash-hls-live-streaming/
- Wowza:
  https://www.wowza.com/solutions/streaming-types/live-video-streaming

Comment: Oh haha! I was completely off the bat then wasn't I. Are there any open source encoders out there. I've found the one supported by bitmovin here I think : https://github.com/slederer/DASHEncoder

Comment: If anyone is looking for live dash encoding there is GPAC :https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/dashcast/